# Restrict character in textbox while copying

Tags: javascript, text, textbox, copy-paste

In my code I have a text box in which users input the location of a document. It needs to be lowercase and cannot include backslashes (). I can limit this when users are typing but not when pasting. The lowercase works if pasting or typing but if I paste the backslash () it will copy. I need to be able to copy and still restrict the backslash. Here is my code. Any ideas?

```
INPUT TYPE="TEXT" 
NAME="newLocation" 
VALUE="#Locvalue#" 
SIZE="40" 
style='text-transform:lowercase' 
onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=220);"
MAXLENGTH="225"
```

Comment: please make your code sample complete and use "code" formatting for better readability

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `onpaste` event

Paste this in a blank .html

```
<input type=text onpaste=delay(this)>
<script type=text/javascript>
function delay(e)
{ setTimeout(function() { e.value=e.value.replace(/\\/g,''); },1);
}
</script>
```